# Image getting stretched when used round shape ImageView

Tags: imageview, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I want to display image in round shape and I am able to display user image in round shape, but not able to manage the image quality.Image is getting shrinked/stretched.I am trying to test it in android device.

Titanium studio information

Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.1.201410281727 Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-202

Device screenshot of stretched image.
http://i60.tinypic.com/23hq9lv.png

My code is as follows.

**View**

```
<View id="userpiceView">
    <ImageView id="userImage" onClick="chooesPic"></ImageView>
</View>
```

**TSS**

```
"#userpiceView":{
    left : "10%",
    width: 84,
    height: 84,
    borderRadius: 42,
    borderColor: '#f05323',
    borderWidth: 3,

}

"#userImage":{

     autorotate: true, 
    image: "/images/defaultuser.png",
    defaultImage: "/images/defaultuser.png",

}
```

**Controller**

```
function chooesPic() {

    Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery(
    {
        mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],

        success : function(event) {
                var imageG = event.media;
                Ti.API.info("before" + imageG.height + " x " + imageG.width);
                Ti.API.info("before" + imageG.length);
                try{

                    var imgBlob = imageG.imageAsResized(300,300);
                    imageG=null;
                    Ti.API.info("after imgBlob " + imgBlob.height + " x " + imgBlob.width);
                    $.userImage.image=imgBlob;
                    imgBlob=null;

                }catch(e){
                    Ti.API.info("Image conversion  error"+e );
                }


            if (event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                var filename = Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + "/" + 'camera_photo' + new Date().getTime() + ".png";
                var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(filename);
                if (f.exists()) {
                    f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(filename);
                }
                f.write(imageG);
                pathfromgallery = f.nativePath;
            }


        }
    });}
```